# SQL Server: Conversion Failure - varchar to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, alm

I am attempting to run a SQL query within ALM (which I have run successfully in the past), and I am receiving the following error:

> [Mercury][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'e2695' to data type int.

Strangely, this error only appears when I change the line `and cast(au_time as date) <= cast('2019/06/19' as date)` to a date larger than '2019/06/16'

```
Select *
From 
    (Select  bg_bug_id           Task_ID,
             bg_summary          Task_Summary,
             bg_user_02          Task_Type,
             bg_user_20          Task_Status,
             bg_user_14          Task_Application,
             bg_user_09          Task_Functional_Tower,
             bg_user_24          Task_Assigned_Team,
             bg_user_27          Task_Assigned_To_Name,
             bg_user_12          Estimated_Fix_date,
             AU_ACTION_ID,
             AU_USER,
             AU_TIME,
             getdate()           CurrentDate,
             AP_PROPERTY_ID,
             AP_OLD_VALUE,
             AP_NEW_VALUE
         From 
             ecs_data_conversion_db.td.bug
         Left Join   
             ecs_data_conversion_db.td.audit_log  On (bg_bug_id = AU_ENTITY_ID)
         Left Join   
             ecs_data_conversion_db.td.audit_properties On (audit_log.AU_ACTION_ID = audit_properties.AP_ACTION_ID and AP_FIELD_Name = 'bg_user_20')
         Where 
             cast(au_time As Date) >=  cast('2019/01/01' As Date)
             and cast(au_time as date) <= cast('2019/06/19' as date)
             and cast(bg_user_20 as varchar) = cast('53 User Acceptance Testing' as varchar)
    ) d_table
Where  
    AP_PROPERTY_ID is not null
Order by 
    task_id, au_time
```

It may help to know that e2695 is a employee ID code. Perhaps less importantly, this user was just provisioned access to the tool which I am trying to query off of.

Comment: Which table is that employeeID coming from?

Comment: seeing LEFT JOIN and WHERE clause in your query also should give some reason to give a heads up comment as those might return results as a INNER JOIN instead, but not sure as we don't know on which table the filter is..

Comment: Please [don't use varchar without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). For a quick reason why, try `SELECT cast('53 User Acceptance Testing 12345' as varchar);`

Comment: The fact that the problem only occurs when you adjust your WHERE clause shows that the problem row is being filtered out by the original WHERE clause, but not by the modified WHERE clause, which should give you the information you need to select exactly the rows with the problem.

Comment: You should ALWAYS reference your columns in your queries by their alias so other people who come behind you know which table a column belongs to. This query is only three tables and it makes my head spin because you have no way of knowing what table anything belongs to. They are just column names. My guess is you are using a type of EAV in your logging which is causing issues because you don't have anything strongly typed.

Comment: Please show the table definitions, and, it is always good form to qualify the columns you select with an alias for the table such as SELECT b.bg_bug_id from ecs_data_conversion_db.td.bug AS b, that way, we will know which tables the column values are coming from.

Comment: My guess would be that in one of your joins you are joining fields of different data types (int on one side varchar(n) on the other), and that previously this hasn't been an issue due to the specific content of the fields. For example if the other employee IDs don't have the leading 'e', but for some reason it has been added in this case.